# Entity showing problems in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, entity

I'm creating a little QA app. I've got Entity Answer which is related to User and Question. I am trying to make a creating form for Answer. I am able to show the list of all the answers, but when it comes to creating a new, there is a problem.
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8GsO.png)

Here is my AnswerEntity code:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\AnswerRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AnswerRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="answers")
 */
class Answer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
     */
    private $answer_text;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Question::class, inversedBy="answer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $question;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAnswerText(): ?string
    {
        return $this->answer_text;
    }

    public function setAnswerText(string $answer_text): void
    {
        $this->answer_text = $answer_text;
    }

    public function getQuestion(): ?Question
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    public function setQuestion(?Question $question): void
    {
        $this->question = $question;
    }
}
```

and the code for AnswerForm

```
/**
 * Answer type.
 */

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Answer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * Class AnswerType.
 */
class AnswerType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * Builds the form.
     *
     * This method is called for each type in the hierarchy starting from the
     * top most type. Type extensions can further modify the form.
     *
     * @see FormTypeExtensionInterface::buildForm()
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder The form builder
     * @param array                                        $options The options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add(
            'AnswerText',
            TextType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'label_answertext',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => ['max_length' => 200],
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Configures the options for this type.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver $resolver The resolver for the options
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => Answer::class]);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the prefix of the template block name for this type.
     *
     * The block prefix defaults to the underscored short class name with
     * the "Type" suffix removed (e.g. "UserProfileType" => "user_profile").
     *
     * @return string The prefix of the template block name
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix(): string
    {
        return 'answer';
    }
}
```

and also **Answer Controller**

```
/**
 * Answer Controller
 */

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Answer;
use App\Entity\Question;
use App\Form\AnswerType;
use App\Repository\AnswerRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Knp\Component\Pager\PaginatorInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Flex\PackageFilter;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class AnswerController.
 *
 * @Route("/answer")
 */

class AnswerController extends AbstractController
{
    private $answerRepository;
    private $answer;
    private $paginator;

    /**
     * AnswerController constructor
     *
     * @param \App\Repository\AnswerRepository $answerRepository Answer Repository
     * @param \Knp\Component\Pager\PaginatorInterface $paginator
     */
    public function __construct(AnswerRepository $answerRepository, PaginatorInterface $paginator)
    {
        $this->answerRepository = $answerRepository;
        $this->paginator = $paginator;
    }

    /**
     * Index action.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request        HTTP request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response               HTTP response
     *
     * @Route(
     *     "/",
     *     methods={"GET"},
     *     name="answer_index",
     * )
     */
    public function index(Request $request, PaginatorInterface $paginator, AnswerRepository $answerRepository): Response
    {
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $answerRepository->queryAll(),
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
            AnswerRepository::PAGINATOR_ITEMS_PER_PAGE
        );

        return $this->render(
            'answer/index.html.twig',
            ['pagination' => $pagination]
        );
    }
    /**
     * Create action.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request HTTP request
     *
     * @param \App\Repository\AnswerRepository $answerRepository Answer repository
     * @param \App\Entity\Answer $answer Answer Entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response HTTP response
     *
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException
     *
     * @Route(
     *     "/create",
     *     methods={"GET", "POST"},
     *     name="answer_create",
     * )
     */
    public function create(Request $request, AnswerRepository $answerRepository, Answer $answer): Response
    {
        $answer = new Answer();
        $form = $this->createForm(AnswerType::class, $answer);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $answerRepository->save($answer);

            $this->addFlash('success', 'answer_created_successfully');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('question_index');
        }

        return $this->render(
            'answer/create.html.twig',
            ['form' => $form->createView()]
        );
    }


}
```

And also, the questions is.., how to route answer/create to make it the answer to the question? I mean, I've localhost/question/{questionid} and I want to create the question here.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is a `ParamConverter` error. In your controller you ask symfony to give you an `Answer $answer` but it cannot provide it because there's no way to do it. you don't need this param in your controller's method.

Also I doubt your `AnswerType` will work since your property is named `answer_text` and your field is named `AnserText`. They must match.

Comment: Thank you, I deleted this param and it worked! :D

Comment: I will try to work on the form now (it was more like a sketch as I get an error earlier). But still get a problem with connecting new answers with question. Do you have any ideas how to do it?

Comment: It's another question. But what you need is to get the question in your controller and set the question of your Answer entity